# The transpose in Banach spaces is bounded below

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear map. Show that: If $T$ is surrjective then its transpose $T':X' \rightarrow X'$ is bounded below.

My try: We know that $R^\perp_M  = N_{M'}$ and since X is surrjective 
$R_M = X$ hence $R_M^\perp = N_{M'} = 0$ so $M'$ is invertible and bounded below.
Am I missing some details? Is invertible and bounded below true?

Comment: The important part seems to be missing: Is it clear to you why $R_{T'}$ is closed? It is *not* assumed that $T$ is injective which you would need in order to conclude that $T'$ is surjective. So, you need to know that the range is closed. If you know that then $T'$ is a continuous bijection from one Banach space onto another, so bounded below follows from the open mapping theorem.

Comment: It is not clear to me why $T$ injective implies $T'$ surjective. Or why it is enough to show that the range is closed, can u please expand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ is a Banach space and $T$ is surjective then by open mapping theorem $T$ is open, i.e.
$$
\{x\in X: \Vert x\Vert\leq c\}\subset \{T(x):\Vert x\Vert\leq 1\}\tag{1}
$$
for some $c>0$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
\Vert T'(x')\Vert
&=\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|T'(x')(x)|\\&=\sup\limits_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|x'(T(x))|\\
&\geq\sup\limits_{ \Vert x\Vert\leq c}|x'(x)|\tag{1}\\
&=\sup\limits_{ \Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|x'(cx)|\\
&=c\sup\limits_{ \Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|x'(x)|\\
&=c\Vert x'\Vert
\end{align}
$$

Comment: should it be closed balls in the second line?

Comment: you can write there open balls, but for my proof closed ones are better

Answer (score 4):

If $T$ is surjective, by the Open Mapping Theorem there is some $c > 0$ such that
for every $y \in X$ there is $x \in X$ with $Tx = y$ and $\|x\| \le c \|y\|$.
Use this to get a lower bound on $\|T'y'\|$ for $y' \in X'$, taking $y$ such that
$|y'(y)|$ is not too small...

Comment: should it be $\|y\| \leq c\|x\|$ and $\|T'y'\|$ ?

Comment: It should be $\|T'y'\|$ (I'll edit).  But I did mean $\|x\| \le c \|y\|$.