# Operator with invertible adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces and $T : X \to Y$ bounded and linear,
such that its adjoint $T^* : X^* \to Y^*$ is boundedly invertible.

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then $T$ is also boundedly invertible, see, e.g., the answer here: [Show $T$ is invertible if $T'$ is invertible where $T\in B(X)$, $T'\in B(X')$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346560/show-t-is-invertible-if-t-is-invertible-where-t-in-bx-t-in-bx/346640#346640)

However, I suspect that this is not true if $X$ or $Y$ are not complete.

Is there a simple example for such a non-invertible $T$ with invertible $T^*$?

**Edit:**
I found some simple examples in case $X$ is not complete: Let $X$ be a dense, proper subspace of an reflexive space $Z$.
Let $T = i_{X}: X \to X^{**} = Z^{**}$ and $S = i_{X^*} : X^*=Z^* \to X^{***}=Z^{***} $ be the canonical embeddings into the biduals. Then, one can show $T^* = S^{-1}$. Hence, $T^*$ is invertible, but $T$ is not.

Therefore, only the case $X$ complete, $Y$ not complete is left. If I do not miss something, we get that $T$ is (not necessarily boundedly) invertible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If $X$ is complete and $Y$ is not, then $T'$ can not be invertible.**

Assume $T'$ is invertible, then it is bijective operator between Banach spaces. Hence $T'$ is bounded below and open mapping.

1) Since $T'$ is bounded below, then by result of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/351605/19538) $T$ is open mapping.

2) Since $T'$ is open mapping by result of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265047/the-transpose-in-banach-spaces-is-bounded-below/265121#265121) operator $T''$ is bounded below. By $i_E$ we denote standard isometric embedding into second dual, then $i_Y T=T'' i_X$. From here we derive that $T$ is also bounded below.

From 1) and 2) we see that $T$ is bounded below and open mapping, hence not only a bijection but an isomorphism. Since $T$ is an isomorphism and $X$ is complete, then so does $Y$. Contradiction.

Comment: So putting it together, we get the following theorem: If $X$ is complete and $T'$ is boundedly invertible, then $T$ is boundedly invertible. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: You are wellcome!

Answer (score 2):

Yes: as you say, $T$ is invertible but the inverse will be unbounded if $Y$ is not complete.

Because one can apply the same proof, to conclude that $T$ is injective and has dense image. The inverse cannot be bounded because if it were we would be able to extend it from $Y$ to its closure, with inverse $T$, and then the image of $T$ would be the closuse of $Y$.

Comment: Our answers contradict to each other. I can't find a mistake neither in yours nor in mine answer. Could you double check them?

Comment: I will. Right now I'm going to "enjoy" a seminar, but I'll check when I come back.

Comment: Have you found mistakes in your or in my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I cannot immediately see how you argue that $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Yes this is the hard part. I've proved this earlier in one of my answers, follow this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351541/proof-of-implication-varphi-text-is-bounded-below-implies-varphi-text-is?lq=1). For credibile resourse see p 333 in the book [Operator spaces by E. G. Effros and Z.J. Ruan](http://bookfi.org/book/1419224)

Comment: I see it now, thanks. Could it be that your argument and mine together show that $T^*$ cannot be boundedly invertible if $X$ is complete while $Y$ is not?

Comment: Right, tt turns out this way.